# DotNetNuke ascx doesn't refresh in browser after html update

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, ascx

I'm currently developing a module in DotNetNuke 8.0.3.

I have a weird problem. I'm pretty sure I was able to make changes on my ascx and pressed F5 to see the changes on my browser. 
Now I have to rebuild everytime.

I have no clue how to resolve the problem.
I think this is IIS problem (something about cache) but I'm not sure.
The files in the desktopmodule update when I save them in visual studio.

**Edit**

I didn't find a fix. I tried several things about caching in IIS or messing up with web.config but it didn't do anything.

Sometimes I can update my page directly and it looks like it happens when IIS change my module into an application

Comment: Have you tried logging into DNN as admin and navigated to Admin -> Skins -> Parse Skin Package?

Answer (score 0):

Login as Host

Navigate Host -> Host Settings

At the bottom, under Advanced settings, there is a setting titled Performance Settings

Expand Performance Settings

Change Cache Setting to None

Click Update

Click Clear Cache